ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint, Received client error (400) from primary with message"{
I have trained mistral 7B model on aws sagemaker, the model weights are stored in S3 location. I have deployed the end point, when I am trying to invoke the endpoint , I am getting the below error
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint
operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message"{
"code": 400,
"type": "InternalServerException",
"message": "\u0027mistral\u0027"
}
please help me
I am tring to invoke the end point in aws sagemaker

It seems the error is from the model container you deployed for the endpoint.
Please check the error logs from your model container for deeper investigation.
